# use abbreviated state names

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I have a map of the US and its 600 x 400.  How do I force it to use the Abbreviated State names which I see in the examples but am unable to reproduce in my own code.

I'm using the below code with some sample data to show the format of the code I'm passing.  I'm having to parse the data out of a larger json response.

```
var data = [{"code":"AK","value":225}, {...} ];
```

This is the map:

```
$('#ha-worst-map-1').highcharts('Map', {
    title : {
        text : result.data[1][2] + ': ' + result.data[1][4]
    },
    subtitle : {
        text : 'stuff and things'
    },
    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'top'
        }
    },
    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },
    credits: {
        text: '',
        href: ''
    },
    series : [{
        data : data,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all'],
        joinBy: ['postal-code', 'code'],
        name: 'metric',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Separators',
        type: 'mapline',
        data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all'], 'mapline'),
        color: 'silver',
        showInLegend: true,
        enableMouseTracking: true
    }]
});
```

Comment: You would need to figure out what `{point.name}` is referencing. Perhaps use `{point.code}`?